# Discord JDA - getMembers() not working, returns 0 anyway

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

This is how my code is looking :

```
public void onGuildVoiceJoin(GuildVoiceJoinEvent event) {
 
    String channelId = event.getChannelJoined().getId();
     
    if (channelId.equals("904375329764814870")) {
         
        Member member = event.getMember();
        String memberName = event.getMember().getEffectiveName();
        Category category = event.getGuild().getCategoryById("904364634507706468");
         
        event.getGuild().createVoiceChannel("Coaching " + memberName).setParent(category).complete();
         
        List<VoiceChannel> channelList = event.getGuild().getVoiceChannelsByName("Coaching " + memberName, true);
        VoiceChannel channel = channelList.get(0);
      
        event.getGuild().moveVoiceMember(member, channel).queue();
         
         
        while (true){
                
            event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("904364671467929610").sendMessage(
                 
               "Number of people currently on the channel : " + channel.getMembers().size()
         
            ).queue();
             
            wait(3000);
                     
        }
```

My goal is to get the number of people currently inside the channel.

I thought the getMembers() method was the good method, but it's not working

I use the infinite while to see if the channel.getMembers().size() changes when i join/leave the channel but it still return 0.

How can i fix this ? And get the correct amount of people inside the channel as return.

Comment: Why are you spamming messages in a while true?

Comment: When you spam messages like that you just create a large queue of messages that will be sent at delays due to rate limits. If the value actually changes, that change will only appear once that queue catches up which can take a long time. Instead, maybe just use a println? The cache for getMembers will also not be updated while your listener keeps running, since all cache is updated by events that can't fire until you return.

Comment: Thank you @Minn , i use a 3seconds delay in the while, i've forgot to paste it here. Is it possible to update the getMembers cache ? The final goal of my code is to delete the channel when he's empty of user. Any idea on how i can do this ?

Comment: have you tried storing each member inside a List? And then getting the current members from the list? For example: List<Member> users  = guild.getMemberCount();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The final goal of my code is to delete the channel when he's empty of user

This can be achieved by just checking the member count in the [GuildVoiceUpdateEvent](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/guild/voice/GuildVoiceUpdateEvent.html):

```java
public void onGuildVoiceUpdate(GuildVoiceUpdateEvent event) {
  if (channel.getName().startsWith("Coaching ")) { // check if name matches the desired name
    if (channel.getMembers().isEmpty()) { // check if channel is empty
      channel.delete().queue(); // delete channel
    }
  } 
}
```